# One-to-Many association without any foreignkey

Tags: xml, hibernate

I know there supposed to be a PK and a FK to associate two tables normally but I'm in a situation where I have no control over the architecture of the legacy system.

My problem is that I want a one-to-many relationship in my xxx.hbm.xml but there aren't any FKs to associate. But the legacy code "depends" on a set of two columns which aren't declared as a composite PK nor FK.

PaymentDelivery is the one side and PaymentItemDelivery is the many side.

I tried this
in paymentDelivery.hbm.xml(the one side)

```
<bag 
        name="paymentItemDelivery"
        fetch="join"
        lazy="false"
        >
        <key>
            <column name="payment_id"></column>
            <column name="delivery_num"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many
            class="kr.co.sgis.services.web.mobile.payment.form.PaymentItemDelivery"
            />

</bag>
```

and other ways but it gives me errors like 
number of columns must match that of the FK or I've got a wrong number of FK columns.
"But I tell you Hibernate, they aren't FKs !"
I've also tried using the properties tag but without any luck. Using properties tags gave me “collection element mapping has wrong number of columns” error too.

The above association was possible through using Annotations like

```
JoinColumns
```

How do I do the same with XML ? 

I also tried this
in paymentDelivery.hbm.xml(one side)

```
<bag 
        name="paymentItemDelivery"
        fetch="join"
        lazy="false"
        >
        <key property-ref="logicalPaymentItemDeliveryAccosiation">

            </key>
            <one-to-many
                class="kr.co.sgis.services.web.mobile.payment.form.PaymentItemDelivery"
                />

        </bag>
<properties 
            insert="false"
            unique="false"
            update="false"
            name="logicalPaymentItemDeliveryAccosiation">

        <property 
            name="payment_id" 
            column="PAYMENT_ID" 
            insert="false" 
            unique="false" 
            update="false">
        </property>

    <property 
        name="delivery_num" 
        column="DELIVERY_NUM" 
        insert="false" 
        unique="false" 
        update="false">
    </property>
</properties>
```

and in paymentItemDelivery.hbm.xml(many side)

```
<properties 
        insert="false"
        unique="false"
        update="false"
        name="logicalPaymentItemDeliveryAccosiation">
        <property 
            name="payment_id" 
            column="PAYMENT_ID" 
            insert="false" 
            unique="false" 
            update="false">

        </property>
        <property 
            name="delivery_num" 
            column="DELIVERY_NUM"
            insert="false" 
            unique="false" 
            update="false">

        </property>
    </properties>
```

It throws

```
collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: 
kr.co.sgis.services.web.mobile.payment.form.PaymentDelivery.paymentItemDelivery
type: component[payment_id,delivery_num]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this working.

I used properties tags and I had to add a unique key to the table !